# How can I determine if my Vulkan install is 32 or 64bit? (64bit Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, version, vulkan

How do I find out if my installed version of Vulkan is 32bit or 64bit? (I'm running 64bit Ubuntu 18.04.1.)

I'm trying to get a 32bit DirectX game (using 64bit Wine) to use Vulkan via "DxVk", and I'm being told by others I need the 32bit version of Vulkan.

I don't know if that's true or not, but all I know (from running: "/usr/bin/vulkaninfo | head -n 100" from the Terminal) is I have v1.1.73 installed. "smoketest" works fine.

TIA.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so I believe is off-topic here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. LunarG offers support for their Vulkan SDk at vulkan.lunarg.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Linux usage. I suggest to re-ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com .